# Gradle error on adding firebase to my Android App

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting started with firebase for realtime database in my android application.My gradle builds just fine but as soon as I add firebase dependencies and classpath,it shows *Enable* *Gradle* '*Offline* *mode*' and sync project.

I have searched a lot but didn't find the solution.Also,the version of Google Play services and Google repository SDK are 38 and 41 respectively.

I have followed each and every step at this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

> My app gradle looks like this-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The project gradle looks like this-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and uncheck **Offline Mode**, and make sure you are connected to internet then sync again. It should resolve it.

Comment: I did that but when I disable the offline mode,it says to enable it and when I enable the offline mode,it says to disable it.Also, I was connected to the internet all the time.